# Logging incoming and outgoing HTTP REST request/response in Spring/Tomcat

Tags: spring, rest, tomcat, logging, spring-4

I have a Spring REST service and sometimes when I request the REST service I get a HTTP 401. I am looking to investigate this issue, this is intermittent and does not happen at all times. (It is the same request that I send everytime).  I also have swagger integrated to provide REST documentation. 
I am deploying my spring REST services as a webapp to Tomcat 7.

1. How can I log the incoming and outgoing HTTP requests even if the request is an unauthenticated request.  I want to be able to tie in ALL the incoming request and their corresponding outgoing response. This is something I would like to roll out into the production application as well.
2. What best practices can I adopt in terms of logging for REST services in Spring, any features I can use that Spring or Tomcat offers for better logging and investigation?

Thanks

Comment: Spring has a default filter to do this see http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/filter/CommonsRequestLoggingFilter.html. If you want more use something like https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-sleuth/ to have centralized logging / tracing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps the best way to do this is to use `Logging framework` in combination with custom `javax.servlet.Filter`. It can trace all HTTP requests/responses separately from other environment that you use in your application (for example Spring MVC or Struts).

> It is important thing that in this case logging must work separately from other
>   parts of application because, otherwise it will depend on some components and does not reflect the real low level events as is or can be broken at all.

I can advise you to use Logback as it has out of the box components that can do what you want.

With `Logback` configuration of your WEB application may look like follows:

**web.xml**

```
<filter>
  <filter-name>TeeFilter</filter-name>
  <filter-class>ch.qos.logback.access.servlet.TeeFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>TeeFilter</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

More details can be found in [Logback documentation](http://logback.qos.ch/access.html#teeFilter).